# how to show user class property at properties window in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to show user class property at properties window.

example, this is class code

```
    public class GraphConstruct
    {
        private List<GC_VisualData> visualDataGroup = new List<GC_VisualData>();
        [Browsable(true), Category("Option"), Description("graph option")]
        public List<GC_VisualData> VisualDataGroup { get { return visualDataGroup; } set { visualDataGroup = value; } }

    }
```

And UserControl contain this code

```
public GraphConstruct CONS = new GraphConstruct();
[Browsable(true), Category("graph option"), Description("graph option")]
public GraphConstruct GRAPH_CONSTRUCT { get { return CONS; } set { CONS = value; } }
```

And properties window showing to me like this.

[image: properties window]

I want to display my class property at properties window like string, enum, int.
Is it posible? If it possible where I start this work?
Please, give me keyword. I don't know how to search it.

have a nice day

Comment: Go to the main menu and select: *View | Class View*. Alternatively press *Ctrl + W* and then *C*. Now you can browse the solution's namespaces and pick the class you want to view. Once you select a class, the window will show all class members. Select one to have more details in the properties view.

Comment: BionicCode-you mean view at main tool bar? I search that menu but I can't find that way.
I'm searching now..
And I install class view in my visual studio and find menu which you told to me!

Comment: If memory serves me right you have to specify an EditorControl for the GraphConstruct class see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/extending-properties-and-the-property-window

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only show the properties of the UserControl itself, which is shown in the properties window when the item is selected in the designer, not the properties of a property within the UserControl.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute?view=net-5.0

Edit: Dependency properties also show up in the properties window - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/dependency-properties-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#property-functionality-provided-by-a-dependency-property

Comment: I do not know how this is done, but it seems to me that you are wrong.
Example: properties Marrgin, Padding - in the property browser there is a separate field for each of their nested properties.

Comment: Margin and padding are both dependency properties of FrameworkElement, so that might be another way to go.

Comment: The documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/exposing-properties-to-the-properties-window?view=vs-2019) does not say anything about dependency properties.